# Function Pointer to a non-static member function?

Tags: c++, winapi, function-pointers, static-members

Is it possible to use a function pointer to point at a non-static member function? I would like to point at a member function that uses non-static objects and variables from the class...static member functions cannot do this...

I have a member function that points at one of four static member functions. The problem is that the data to be used by each of the four member functions is non-static so the static member functions will not access them...

Can I point at non-static member functions?

Also, the class instance is a pointer...here is my code:

```
class CRoutine{
int m_index;
    ...
        BOOL (*CallRoutine(char opcode))(DWORD, float, float, float);
        static BOOL Update(DWORD, float, float, float);
        static BOOL Transition(DWORD, float, float, float);
        static BOOL Revert(DWORD, float, float, float);
        static BOOL Sequence(DWORD, float, float, float);
    ...
    };
    BOOL (*CRoutine::CallRoutine(char opcode))(DWORD, float, float, float)
    {   
        switch ( opcode )
        {
        case 0:
            return &CRoutine::Update;
        case 1:
            return &CRoutine::Transition;
        case 2:
            return &CRoutine::Revert;
        case 3:
            return &CRoutine::Sequence;
        default:
            return &CRoutine::Update;
        }
    }
    BOOL CRoutine::Update(DWORD AnimSetIndex, float time, float tTime, float shift)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Updating", L"Routine #1", MB_OK);
         CRoutine::m_index++; // Error thrown here...       
return true;
    }
    BOOL CRoutine::Transition(DWORD AnimSetIndex, float time, float tTime, float shift)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Transitioning", L"Routine #2", MB_OK);
        return true;
    }
    BOOL CRoutine::Revert(DWORD AnimSetIndex, float time, float tTime, float shift)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Reverting", L"Routine #3", MB_OK);
        return true;
    }
    BOOL CRoutine::Sequence(DWORD AnimSetIndex, float time, float tTime, float shift)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Sequencing", L"Routine #4", MB_OK);
        return true;
    }
```

The error thrown above is:
error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'CRoutine::m_index'

Comment: "*Is it possible to use a function pointer to point at a non-static member function?*" No, but it's possible to use a _member function pointer_ to point at a non-static member function...

Comment: I see the difference thanks...found an article on member function pointers...http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible

Comment: See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes as long as you can modify the type in which it is stored.

Using the std::function abstract you can bind to anything that meets a certain signature (ie take x return y). be it functor, lambda, bound member function or free function.

```
struct bar{
     void foo(){
          std::cout << "HI" << std::endl;
    } 
};

int main(){

    bar b;
    //using std::function instead of a func*
    std::function<void()> func(
                 std::bind(&bar::foo, &b));

    func();
}
```

Note the use of std::function require C++11, boost has a very similar version too that can be used with C++98